# css height 80% not working

Tags: css

I want to make my table take up 80% of the screen, but right now its only the size of the content in the table.

```
#ecom-mainarea .center
{
margin-left: 10%;
position: relative;
width: 80%;
height: 80%;   /* when this is 500px it works fine, but % doesn't work */ 
border: 1px solid;
border-bottom-color: teal;
border-top-color: gray;
border-left-color: gray;
border-right-color: teal;
background-color: white;
voice-family: "\"}\"";
voice-family: inherit;
vertical-align: text-top;
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to make sure that the `html`and `body` elements have `100%` height. They need to stretch from top to bottom. If not the `html` and `body` element will just be as high as your table.

Here you have a working sample:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Table height</title>
    <style>
        html, body
        {
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
            height: 100%;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <table style="background: cyan; height: 80%;">
        <tr>
            <td>
                Table has 80% of the height of the body
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Works fine so long as you specify a height of the parent element (in absolute units)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a bit of a hack. It uses positioning. See: http://jsfiddle.net/minitech/2vRrZ/

(Also, if you ever need vertical centering for multiple lines - that's how it's done. My invention as far as I know)

Comment: You don't need an image. I've seen this before, not sure where though. http://jsfiddle.net/2vRrZ/4/

Comment: @thirtydot: I wanted to avoid `inline-block`. Though I suppose it won't work on IE6 anyways.

Answer (score 0):

If I recall, percent is not supported for CSS heights. Gotta resort to other methods.

Comment: Weird. The width seems to be working.  Any suggestions for other methods?

Comment: I should clarify - I don't think it works with the browser height, but it should work relative to its container.

Answer (score 0):

As a design suggestion unless you really want to have it as a percentage I'd suggest a fixed size for the table so the layout looks the same on every computer no matter what their resolution is.

Comment: fixed. I was unaware that they were such controversy, thank you for sharing.