# CSS - can't get min-height working

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a really simple webpage. It should be a 1000px wide green, centered rectangle stretching all the way from the top to the bottom of the webpage on a red background, no matter how much content there is.

I can't get this working though. If I use `min-height` (like below), the green area doesn't stretch all the way to the bottom of the page if there's not enough content. If I replace it by `height`, the content overflows the green area if there's much content.

Here's my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container">
            content here.
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here's the CSS:

```
html {
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    background-color: #F00;
    margin: 0;
    min-height: 100%;
}

#container {
    background-color: #0F0;
    width: 1000px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 100%;
}
```

I know this is feasible with more `div`s, but it really should work without changing the HTML. How can I solve this?

By the way, I'm on Safari. I don't care about compatibility with browsers not respecting standards.

Comment: Does http://stackoverflow.com/questions/485827/css-100-height-with-padding-margin help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a working sample:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Container sample</title>
    <style>
        html, body
        { 
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            height: 100%;
            background: red;
        }
        #container 
        {
            background: green;
            width: 1000px;
            min-height: 100%;
            margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        Container sample
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

For more information take a look at [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6718882/css-height-80-not-working/6718970#6718970) to a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6718882/css-height-80-not-working).

Answer (score 1):

you can use property `position absolute` for your requirement. It may help you

```
 #container {
    background-color: #0F0;
    width: 1000px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    left:50%;
    margin-left:-500px;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately that stops the green area from being centered.

Answer (score 0):

Give your `#container` a `position:absolute;` with `top` and `bottom` set to `0`.

```
#container {
    background-color: #0F0;
    width: 1000px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/4ZLcD/